# Location based pricing on HTML website

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

We have a simple HTML5/CSS3 website. We wish to change the pricing table based on location of the visitor.

For example, all users from Singapore see a fixed price and the rest of the world a different price on our pricing.html page.

What is the simplest (and free) way to achieve this ? Cross Browser compatibility would be good and we would want to automate the process rather than prompting the visitor for location.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards
Gary

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how to do it, but I guess HTML5 geolocation would be pretty helpfull!

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

You could simply call for a location. Then you have to know the lat- and longitude area of Singapore and compare it. Then you could just set the price with javascript or show and hide some pricing divs or whatever.

The only problem is that this works only in FF, Safari, Chrome and IE9+. If you need to go lower on IE you could try node.js.